# Attach event to dynamically created button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I want to attach an event to a button clicked generated at runtime. Till this point I've wrote the code, but can't pass the button's ID to the method. Here is my code

This code does not through any error, another problem is after the click event the controls get washed away. How to prevent this ?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     int i = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
     for (int x = 1; x <= i; x++)
     {
       Button b = new Button();
       b.ID = "btn_" + x.ToString();
       b.Text = "btn_" + x.ToString();
       b.Click += new System.EventHandler(myEventHandler);
       pnlHolder.Controls.Add(b);
     }
   }

 private void myEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   txtMain.Text = sender.ToString(); // I want to know which button was pressed
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try,

```
txtMain.Text = (sender as Button).Name;
```

or

```
txtMain.Text = (sender as Button).Text;
```

Comment: **Sender as button** Just loved it (: +1

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 private void myEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   Button b = (Button) sender;
   txtMain.Text = b.ID;
   //
   txtMain.Text = b.Text;

   if(b.ID == "button1")
     doThis();
   else if(b.ID == "button2")
     doThat();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, +1, btw can you help me with the another problem ? [controls removed after postback]

Comment: Asp.net is not like window forms. Controls state are lost at postback. That's why ASP.Net uses ViewState to remember controls you add through design or markup. You'll need to make your buttons as part of ViewState or recreate them everytime the page refreshes